# Query MySQL LIKE with dot separator

Tags: mysql

i have field in mysql type varchar with field data contains code, and the code is like tree structure with dot (.) as separator between parent and child.

Example `1215` has child `1215.001` and `1215.002`

And this is the data each row on database

```
ID  | kode
1   | 1215
2   | 1215.001
3   | 1215.001.001
4   | 1215.002.001
5   | 1215.002
6   | 1215.002.001
```

How to get the level 2 code?
which its mean will be only the code `1215.001` and `1215.002`

Already tried with this query

```
select * from `kegiatan` where `kode` LIKE '1215.%';
```

But it get all the code start with `1215` eg: `1215.001.001`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression.

```
 select * from `kegiatan` where `kode` REGEXP '^1215\.[^\.]+$';
```

This will match everything:

```
 That starts with ( "^" )

 the string "1215.",

 followed by at least one character that is a member of the set "NOT ." ("[^\.]+")

  followed by the end of the string.("$")
```

Comment: oh yes nice, i have feeling if this will be good can be done through regex :D

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular expression for this;

```
select * from `kegiatan` where `kode` REGEXP '^1215.[0-9]+$';
```

Which will match items beginning with `^1215`, followed by a period `.`, followed by one or more numeric values `[0-9]+`, followed by the end of the string `$`.

This will match `1215.001` and `1215.002`, but not `1215` or `1215.001.001`

Hope it helps,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct substr(kode,1,8)  from `kegiatan` where `kode` LIKE '1215.%';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: can you give link documentation abous `substr`, im new with it @_@. It will be nice if i can learn about it.

Comment: Edited with link. You'll see other string functions on the same page